# Wp_query items from array of id's at the beginning of the query

Tags: arrays, wordpress, sorting

I have an array of items for example:

```
ids = array(112,113,114);
```

and have a `wp_query` that returns a list of posts including the posts with the id's listed in the `ids` array

I need to sort the `wp_query` posts o that will show the `112, 113, 114` then the rest of the posts from the query

I was thinking maybe I can sort the items by the `ids` array like this

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'   => ids,
    'order'     => 'ASC'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `post_in` parameter so you can achieve the result as you want. below code will work.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'your_post_type',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'post__in',
    'order'     => 'ASC', 
    'post__in' => array(112,113,114)
);
```

so above code will only order posts given in `post_in` parameter.

Tested and works well.

Comment: Yes, but I want to show all posts, not just the ones I specify in the array.

Comment: run two query first above one then in second one exclude those above posts using `exclude` parameter this is the only way to achieve result you intended.